# CSS filter video but not the controls

Tags: javascript, css, filter, controls, blur

As is displayed here: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zbakI
you can apply a filter to videos using css filters.

You define the filter and then you refer to it later when applying it to the video element.

```
var blur_name='the_blur';
master_video.style.webkitFilter='url(#'+blur_name+')';
master_video.style.mozFilter='url(#'+blur_name+')';
master_video.style.filter='url(#'+blur_name+')';

var blur_name='';
master_video.style.webkitFilter='';
master_video.style.mozFilter='';
master_video.style.filter='';
```

But how can i get the filter to not blur the controls of the video?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you will have to use custom video controls.  There are lots of resources out there that explain how to implement them, for example [this article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos).

I've edited a fiddle I found on Google to illustrate this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/td8Lao79/

I am applying a simple `filter: blur(4px);` to the video element, but you can define your filters in HTML and refer to them by ID if you prefer.