# Make video playing behind a div fuzzy

Tags: javascript, css, filter

Using css filters we can make a div, with all of its subcontent fuzzy by applying a css filter to it in the following manner.

In the HTML:

```
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="blur"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" /></filter></svg>
```

Then in the javascript:

```
document.getElementById('id_of_div_being_blurred').style.filter='url(#blur)';
document.getElementById('id_of_div_being_blurred').style.webkitFilter='url(#blur)';
```

This works fine, but the issue is that i do not have access to the content i am blurring. Is there any way for me to make whatever is undeneath my div, fuzzy as a consequence of the div i have over it?

Comment: Nope. But you could add a wrapper to the video element with JS and filter that. Do filters work on video's? not sure

Comment: yeah they work on videos http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zbakI but i cant-not fuzzify the controls nor control which part of the video is to be fuzzy.

Comment: the controls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892190/css-filter-video-but-not-the-controls

Comment: You'd have to create your own controls separate from the video I guess

Comment: yeah. the default video controls have tons of more defects anyways.

Comment: The thing is i need to fuzzify the video sometimes and sometimes not, without having access to it. Guess I need to go around this somehow.

Comment: Add a wrapper with JS. Toggle a class on the wrapper with JS?

Comment: yeah if i had access to the video that would be no problem. but my script is being referred to by another script, and this other script has the video that is being run in the background. Maybe i'll just make an ajax call or something.